# Operations on singly linked list in C++ (with int and char variables)

Tags: c++, list, singly-linked-list

I'm a beginner programmer in C++ and my problem concerns implementing operations on singly linked list.
My single linked list must have both "char" and "int" variables and be able to: remove and add elements (at the beginning/end) on the list and display all list elements.

Before I describe in-detail what is the problem, please have a look at the code I've managed to make so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct FunnyList {
    int iValue;
    char *cName;
    FunnyList *next;
};

int main()
{
    FunnyList *base;
    FunnyList *traversal;

    base = new FunnyList;       
    base->next = 0;             
    base->cName = "Alicia";       
    traversal = base;           
    if(traversal != 0) {
        while( traversal->next != 0) {
            traversal = traversal->next;
        }
        cout << traversal->cName << endl;
    }

    traversal->next = new FunnyList;   
    traversal = traversal->next;    
    traversal->next = 0;           
    traversal->cName = "Octavia";

    while(traversal->next != 0) {
        traversal = traversal->next;    
    }
    cout << traversal->cName << endl;

    traversal->next = new FunnyList;    
    traversal = traversal->next;        
    traversal->next = 0;                
    traversal->cName = "Tom";

    while(traversal->next != 0) {
        traversal = traversal->next;    
    }
    cout << traversal->cName << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that:

1)
I am aware that I probably need to implement functions: 
- insert() 
- remove() 
- display()

which are of the form (?):

- void insert_el(char *cName, int iValue);
- void delete_el(char *cName);
- void print();

instead of implementing them in main() but I don't know how to make it compatible with my part of code.

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: It looks like you need some time learning about operator new, delete, and classes, including constructors, destructrors, methods, etc. I don't often say it, but in this case it is fairly accurate: You need a book; a *good* book. If you already knew about these things an just wanted this written anyway I'd say use a standard container (`std::vector<>`, `std::list<>`, etc..) but there are some pretty core things it looks like you need to learn first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this plain old `C`-style you usually have functions that are responsible for working on your list. Like

```
insert_node(struct FunnyList* previous, struct FunnyList* item);
remove_node(struct FunnyList* base, struct FunnyList* item);
print_nodes(struct FunnyList* base);
```

These functions take either your head-node or a sibling node as an anchor an perform operations on them.

If you try it the `OO`-way using `C++`, you will have an object that behaves like `std::vector` or `std::list` and takes care of this. The difference here is, that your data and the functions on the data are encapsulated in an object and you will not operate on the raw data itself. [Here](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/linkedlist.htm) is a `C++`-style tutorial on linked lists.

[Here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html) is a simple *C*-style example and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) article from Wikipedia.